# ASP.NET Testing DbContext in local methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, and am writing my service something along the lines of this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public void AddUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid){
            var user = new User
            {
                FirstName = userModel.FirstName,
                LastName = userModel.LastName,
                Email = userModel.Email,
                Age = userModel.Age
            };
            using (var context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                context.Users.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }
    //... More code for service
}
```

And my DbContext class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public MyDbContext(): base("name=mydb"){}

    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}

    //.. More domain objects.
}
```

This runs fine for the most part, but the problem arises when I want to try and test it. I'm following the general guidelines [here](http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/517/mocking-dbset-queries-in-ef6/) with mocking it out, but that's only if the DbContext is declared as a class instance, as opposed to a functional variable. I want to do it this way because it enables me to have control over the transaction and context disposal. Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

My mocks are like this:

```
public class UserServiceTest 
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestAddUser()
    {
        var userSet = GetQueryableMockDbSet(userData.ToArray());
        var context = new MyDbContext
        {
            Users = userSet
        };
        var userService = new UserService();
        userService.AddUser(); // HOW DO I GET CONTEXT IN HERE?
    }   

    private static DbSet<T> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(params T[] sourceList) where T : class
        {
            var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();

            var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());

            return dbSet.Object;
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass your `DbContext` to the service's constructor. Read on Dependency Injection and use some IoC container to make things easier

Comment: He can't pass the instance to the container as he stated he wants to control creation of the instance inside the method.  I was thinking perhaps OP can inject a `Factory` into the service which will create the instance, and then mock the Factory create method with the mock object

Comment: The factory method seems promising: would it be something like FactoryContext.Create() returns an MyDbContext item? The Create method is static, obviously.

Comment: Yes @IvanPeng that's exactly the idea I had, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal of

> I want to do it this way because it enables me to have control over the transaction and context disposal.

Would be to do something along the lines of

```
public class UserService : IUserService {
   private ContextFactory _ContextFactory;

   public UserService(ContextFactory contextFactory) {
       _ContextFactory = contextFactory;
   }

   public void AddUser(UserModel userModel) {
       ...
       using (var context = _ContextFactory.CreateInstance()) {
           context.Users.Add(user);
       }
   }
```

}

This would allow you to inject different instances of `ContextFactory` which would create the `DbContext` using the Mock

Answer (score 1):

I would definetly prefer the IOC approach but If you want a quick solution without rewriting too much code you can do something like this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService 
{
    public static Func<MyDbContext> CreateContext = () => new MyDbContext();

    public UserService ()
    {
    } 

    public void AddUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        ...
        using (var context = CreateContext())
        {
            context.Users.Add(user);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't have to change your production code but in your TestMethod you can do

```
    var context = new MyDbContext
    {
        Users = userSet
    };
    UserService.CreateContext = () => context;
```

Comment: Although this technically doesn't follow best practices, which is what I was trying to do, I still really love this answer. Simple and cheeky.

Comment: Yes, if you already follower IOC patterns injecting a new dependency into a class is a piece of cake but if have to change 50 constructors in your code this is a nice solution. I believe this is a common pattern for third party libs (I think I have seen this in quartz.net or nuget.core). It keeps the code simpel, does not need a dependency to an IOC container but stil keeps the flexibility to inject objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the **DbContext** in the *constructor* of the service. The easiest way to do that is to start using any IoC framework (AutoFac,Unity, Ninject etc). To *mock* the database the easisest way is to start using any mocking library like Moq and RhinoMocks.

```
public class UserService : IUserService 
{
    private MyDbContext _context;

    public UserService (MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
    } 
}
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I'm aware of this method, but I'd rather not because I want to be in control of my transactions here, and manage context disposal.

Comment: However you need to pass the context to the service. Either in the constructor or in the method. If you do it with a IoC-framework they will handle the disposal for you in a good manner.

Comment: And when you writing tesst the test class itself should "own" the dbContext (mocked or not) not the class under test.